# Is making a youtube channel with gaming videos haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I am wondering if having a youtube channel with gaming videos is haram. People might use it irresponsibly and waste time, would this be my responsibilty? Thank you.

Comment: it should not be haram as long as it does not contain any source of haram things or promote anything against the islamic law. In terms of responsibility and time wastage, it depends on the users who come to your youtube channel.

Comment: winter bucky would it be my responsibility if they waste too much time though?

Comment: as long as you keep your side with the halaal things, you don't have to worry about others on the time wastage as this is more towards the users responsibility instead of yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game itself should be halal and you should first advice them not to spend too much time in that game.If you do it I think it'll be fine.After that if they waste too much time in that game then it will be their responsibility because you already adviced them.There is no problem to play halal games for entertainment for short time.But if you start wasting time it'll become Haram.
And finally,I want to say,there's no benefit in making gaming videos.Whats the purpose? Isn't this useless? You should spend your time in some beneficial activities.
But however it's not Haram as long as you don't get addicted in playing games and I believe making gaming videos is also okay as long as you follow the above things which I wrote.
And Allah knows best!

Comment: thank you, I enjoy making gaming videos so thats why and i was asking,

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I want to remind you of surah al muminun 3rd verse:

*"and who turn away from all that is vain"*

Isn't wasting precious time with games vain? For me the answer is **"yes"**

And think about the time people lose when they watch your vides. If you have a popular 10 minute video watched 1 million times, that would be 2778 hours of watching time.